# z-index / border related issue with nav menu

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/FS4zT/

If you visit the above link you see what am describing below.
Summary: I have set the z-index of the submenu to 99 and the z-index top level menu to 9..
So basically i was thinking when i move the mouse over to the 1st menu, the 1st submenu will stay in focus when i move the mouse over the items of the submenu.

But for some reason in Firefox 11.0 it switches over to the 2nd Top Level Menu when i try to move my mouse over the 2nd/3rd/4th items of the first sub menu.

In IE 7 : It works as desired by i can still see the border of the 2nd Top Level Menu overlapping the items of the sub-menu even tho their z-index is higher. The border problem can be even seen in firefox.

Can someone shed some light where i might be going wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should fix it, I hope.

```
#menu li ul li { 
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Can you please (if possible) explain why setting position: relative; makes it work?

Comment: You're welcome :) HTML elements are positioned static by default. A static positioned element is always positioned according to the normal flow of the page. Static positioned elements are not affected by the top, bottom, left, right and z-index properties. Reference: [CSS Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp), [Z-Index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: this answer and "background-color: white" worked to me

Answer (score 1):

Beware of the stacking context of the z-index. What you want is not working for parent-child z-indices.

The problem is that the parent `li` of the submenu is not as wide as the submenu (4x times smaller). So if you hover to the right, the `li` loses focus.

One way to solve this, is setting `z-index: 0` on al `ul` submenus and `z-index: 1` on the current submenu. The submenu's should have `position: absolute`.

Update: Solution with `position: relative` (accepted answer) is really a good one. This is working because the `li`s of the submenu do not make the parent container larger since they are left floated.

Comment: I think you haven't visited the link i had given, i do show or hide the sub-menu with display property.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the height in #menu li

```
#menu li {
    width: 140px;
    height: 25px;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px inset white;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

The other way you can go to keep your borders at 50px is when you add to the CSS something like this.

```
#menu li:hover ~ li{
    height:25px;
}
```

Comment: I need the borders on the items of top level menu to have vertical left & rights borders of 50px height.
PS: The sub-menu items should have have the borders.

Comment: The problem was solved by mrsafraz, thanks for the help tho sven. By the way is ~ the sibling selector?

Comment: Yes it is the sibling selector for all siblings